# Difference between NumPy's vectorize and its automatic vectorization

Tags: python, numpy

I want to do many random walks and plot them. The function that jumps from initial state `istate` to the next state is simply `iter = lambda istate: istate + np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5)`.

So, given an NumPy array 'arr' with the values of each walk, if I simply call `iter(arr)`, the function `iter` is vectorized but it performs the same die throw for all of the elements.
If I instead call `np.vectorize(iter)(arr)` the function performs an individual die throw for each element.

What is the difference between the two vectorizations? does this affect performance when using other kinds of functions?

Comment: `np.vectorize` sends scalar values to the function.  It can be a convenience when your function only works with scalar values, but it doesn't promise any speed.

Comment: Side note, you could do something like: `a = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, (10, 5))` to do 10 random walks of 5 steps. Reading left-to-right, you can boost the starting value with something like `a[:, 0] += 5`, and then do `print(np.cumsum(a, axis=1))`. That doesn't answer your question, but will certainly be much faster

Comment: `np.vectorize` is basically a loop. When you call `iter`(arr), you are essentially doing: `arr + np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5)`, i.e. you are adding the same random number to all the vector.  
PS: Try doing `np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, size=n).cumsum()` for a random walk of `n` steps

Comment: Side note: don't shadow the built-in name `iter`.

Answer (score 2):

`np.vectorize` is for functions that don't accept an ndarray as argument, and is roughly a for loop, so never efficient. for example :

```
a=np.arange(1e4,dtype=float)
float.hex(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-e5cdcd882026>", line 1, in <module>
    float.hex(a)

TypeError: descriptor 'hex' requires a 'float' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

`np.vectorize` allows this operation :

```
%timeit np.vectorize(float.hex)(a)
14.6 ms ± 850 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

approximately equivalent to (in result and performance):

```
%timeit [float.hex(z) for z in a]
14.2 ms ± 666 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

But here  your `iter` (renamed `my_iter`) accepts ndarrays :

```
def my_iter(x): return x+np.random.uniform(-.5,.5)

%timeit my_iter(a)
16.1 µs ± 1.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Far better in this case than :

```
%timeit np.vectorize(my_iter)(a)
28.6 ms ± 6.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

The NumPy’s [vectorized operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#using-an-external-loop), *i.e.*, the `np.vectorize(iter)(array)` can be used on larger chunks of the visited elements. This vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop. On the other hand, [by default](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values), the `iter(array)` treats the input array as a read object. It is used to obtain an iterator over that given object. If the iterator is defined to return a *new* object it would make it so that it could iterate as many times as wanted.